# Meaning must and operator combination

Tags: elasticsearch

my coding as below:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "multi_match": {
              "query": [
                 "5347"
              ],
              "fields": [
                 "stkno",
                 "tag",
                 "content",
                 "htext"
              ],
              "operator": "or"
           }
        }
     ]
  }
 },
 "size": 500,
 "sort": [
  {
     "CDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

what meaning if must and operator combine together? Elasticsearch will run with condition if using must and operator is or?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`Must` is like `And` between multiple queries.
Take for example :

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {  // Query 1},
           { // Query 2}
        ]
     }
   }
```

Above query will return results if both `Query1` **AND** `Query2` return results. Study about `must` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Whereas `operator` **OR** in above query holds for `multi_match` query.

Take for example:

```
    "multi_match": {
              "query": [
                 "text1 text2"
              ],
              "fields": [
                 "field1",
                 "field2"
              ],
              "operator": "or"            
           }
```

Here **OR** operator will work between `text1` and `text2` mentioned in `multimatch` query. That means If any of the fields `field1` or `field2` contains `text1` **OR** `text2`, document will be returned. Study about `operator` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#operator-min)

Now if we consider your example given above. Since you have only one query in `must` clause, you won't be able to see **AND** behaviour.

And you have only text in `multimatch` query which is "5347" , you won't be able to see **OR** behaviour of multimatch query

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: how about if text 1 and test 2 is "4448.KL " and "6599.KL" and operation is 'And' and multimatch also , it only  can find "6599.KL" , then 4448.KL can;t finding, also because of multimatch?

Comment: Did not get you. Can you specify the query you run?

Comment: POST news/bursa/_search 
{  
  "query": { "bool": {   "must": [{ "match": { "category": "36" } } ],"must":  [ { "multi_match": { "query": [ "4448.KL","6599.KL" ], "fields": [  "stkno", "tag"  ,"content"  ,"htext"  ] ,"operator": "and"} } ],"must":  [{ "range": { "CDate": {  "gt": "2010-01-01" ,  "lte": "2017-05-30T23:59:59"  } } } ]  } },  "size": 1000, "sort": [ { "CDate": { "order": "desc" } } ] }

Comment: above is my query....at category:36, 4448.KL","6599.KL sure have inside the indices...but it only can search 6599.KL, and 4448.KL can't find

Comment: I think your query is not correct. you can not specify array in `multi_match` query clause. Gives this error `[multi_match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]"`

Comment: can..i get the result.. only result only showing "6599.KL". but can't find "4448.KL". This 4448.KL also inside the elasticsearch

Comment: You have specified `AND` operator . It will fetch only those documents which have both 6599.KL, and 4448.KL. Documents having only 4448.KL won't be searched

Comment: Can we make as sql below: